# Query from template in Django

Tags: django

I am coming from Ruby-on-Rail background. I have a user table and an employee table.

In the index page of all the employee, I am looking to retrieve their first name which is in the user model and not in the employee table.

I tried the following which is very rubyesque:

```
{% User.objects.filter(id=employee.user_id) %}
```

But i get the error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 163: 'User.objects.filter(id=employee.user_id)', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Although the user_id clearly exists.

What is the best way for such queries in Django please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add context in your view to access data in template like following:

```py
def detail(request):
    # define employee 
    context = {'users': User.objects.filter(**filter_criteria)}
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', context=context)
```

then in your template you can use

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, but this is for the detail page. i am working at the index view, where i list all the employees please.

Comment: @FrankyDoul I have updated my answer, you can use for loop in templates.

Comment: @FrankyDoul Please mark the answer as accepted, if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hey that does not work sorry. See the solution below please.

Comment: why didn't it work? it should work equally like your solution but easier to understand and code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an query from as list in a template, I found the following solution, which can be used and re-used.

I add a `templatetags` folder right below my app folder. inside that `templatetags` folder, I create a file `custom_tags.py` and an empty file `__init__.py`. It should look like this :
[image: App architecture]

Then in the `custome_tags` file i add the following:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from app.models import User
from app.models import Employee

@register.simple_tag
def find_user_firs_last_name(user_id):
    user = User.objects.filter(id = user_id ).last()
    return user.first_name + " " + user.last_name if user else None
```

This function will take the user_id and look up through the user table and return the first and last name if any.

Then in the view:

```
{% for employee in employees %}
...
<a class="mb-0 text-sm" href="{% url 'details_employee' employee.id %}"> 
{% find_user_firs_last_name employee.user_id %} </a>
...
{% endfor %}
```